# Convertir en array un objeto que contiene mas objetos

Tags: array, string, split

estoy tratando de convertir un string en array, no he logrado separar los dos objetos que estan dentro del string, estoy intentando con la funcion split() pero aun no logro separarlos. Esto necesito mapearlo asi que necesito los dos objetos por aparte cada uno... gracias por su ayuda.

```js
let dubbed = "{"idioma":"frances ", "id":1695, "title":"A La Mano ", "url":"/es/produccion/la-mano"},{"idioma":"mandarin ", "id":1742, "title":"\"Colombia Bio / Todo es un Fragmento\"", "url":"/es/produccion/colombia-bio-todo-es-un-fragmento"}";
    const arrayDubbed = dubbed.split([", "]);
    console.log(dubbed);
    console.log(arrayDubbed);
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el lenguaje? Además, en todos los lenguajes que conozco esto fallaría porque las " sin escapar cerrarían el string y daría un error de compilación.

Answer (score 2):

Vayamos por pasos.

Lo primero es asegurarse que el contenido de `dubbed` sea correcto.

Al declarar un string hay que tener en cuenta que si usamos el mismo tipo de comillas hay que escaparlas.

Un ejemplo

```
console.log("Este string "no" es válido")
console.log("Pero este string está \"bien\" escapado")
console.log('Esta es otra forma de "hacerlo" ')
```

Entendido esto. Lo siguiente es que ese string no es un JSON correcto. Una lista de objetos en JSON debe ir dentro de `[]`

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ es una página muy cómoda para ver que parte es incorrecta dentro de tu json.

Si aplicamos todos estos cambios nos quedará algo así:

```js
     const dubbed = "[{\"idioma\":\"frances \", \"id\":1695, \"title\":\"A La Mano \", \"url\":\"/es/produccion/la-mano\"},{\"idioma\":\"mandarin \", \"id\":1742, \"title\":\"\\\"Colombia Bio / Todo es un Fragmento\\\"\", \"url\":\"/es/produccion/colombia-bio-todo-es-un-fragmento\"}]"
     
console.log(dubbed)
     
const parsed = JSON.parse(dubbed)

console.log(parsed)
```

Nótese que hemos usado el método mas "complejo" para escapar las comillas porque he visto que uno de los valores tiene escapes dentro del JSON y con comillas simples esos escapes no funcionarína

Una ves tenemos hecho eso el problema es pasar el string a un objeto. Y eso lo podemos hacer con `JSON.parse`

Finalmente, suponiendo que por algún motivo no puedes cambiar ese string a una lista.. esta sería una forma de obtener ambos objetos:

```js
     const dubbed1 = "{\"idioma\":\"frances \", \"id\":1695, \"title\":\"A La Mano \", \"url\":\"/es/produccion/la-mano\"},{\"idioma\":\"mandarin \", \"id\":1742, \"title\":\"\\\"Colombia Bio / Todo es un Fragmento\\\"\", \"url\":\"/es/produccion/colombia-bio-todo-es-un-fragmento\"}"
    
const [first, second] = dubbed1.split('},{')
    
firstJson = JSON.parse(first + '}')
secondJson = JSON.parse('{' + second)
    
console.log(firstJson)
console.log(secondJson)
```

El problema de este método es que el split lo hacemos por `},{` y si el contenido de alguna cadena dentro del json coincide se romperá y no es muy fiable... por lo que recomiendo usar el primer método si es posible